# Lua code deobfuscation

Tags: lua

Есть скрипт Lua обускацированный, скорее всего с помощью XFuscator, возможно ли деобускацировать и получить исходный код?

**Обновление**

[Такой вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15961156/4827341) ничего не дает,

Часть кода

```
local ________ = ____[#____ - 9]("loadstring(\"return ____\")()")
local __ = {
  _(54),
  _(152),
  _(234),
  _(194),
  _(162),
  _(0),
  _(2),
  _(8)}
local ________ = ____[3]
return ____[11](assert(#____[8](__) == 15889 and ____[8](__) or nil, "Tampering detected"), ____[#____])()
```

Comment: внести изменения в текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, в http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961156/lua-code-deobfuscation писали о некой возможности деобфускации. Вы можете подробнее расписать, как записать файл в биткоде, а потом декомпилировать в читаемый код Lua (допустим обфускацированный файл 123.lua)? Может что-то ни так делаю.

Comment: XFuscator строит код, который делает бессмысленные отвлекающие манипуляции переменными, а потом просто загружает байт-код.  Вам не надо ковыряться в этом отвлекающем коде - просто перехватите вызов к loadstring и получите байт-код в готовом виде.  Сложность в понимании байт-кода.  Вызывайте `luac -l -l файл_с_байт-кодом` и фтыкайте.  Байт-код не совместим с другими версиями Lua, и этим плох XFuscator.  Фтыкать в байт-код нужно на той же версии (версия луа определяется по пятому байту байт-кода: 0x51 = Lua 5.1).  Для Lua 5.1 есть декомпилятор, строящий по байт-коду более читаемый Lua исходник.

Comment: [декомпилятор луа 5.1](https://github.com/sztupy/luadec51/downloads)

Comment: @Maxim - через `@Username` можно выслать оповещения только тем, кто что-то запостил в этой ветке.  Так работает движок SO.  Увы, позвать кого-то со стороны в тему нельзя.